# How to set gradient background color to NSButton?

Tags: macos, gradient, background-color, nsbutton

I want to set my NSButton(not UIButton) background color to gradient color as like below image. I added background color for NSbuttoncell, But How to add gradient color ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use [**NSGradient**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSGradient_class/index.html).

```
- (instancetype)initWithStartingColor:(NSColor *)startingColor
                          endingColor:(NSColor *)endingColor
```